# SQL Server : why doesn't this query return NULL values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with one column named value, of type int, and 4 rows in it:

```
20
50
NULL
0
```

Why does this query return 20 and 50 only? I need NULL values, too.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE value != 0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In SQL, `NULL` is a special value, nothing can ever be equal to or not equal to it. In fact, `NULL` doesn't even equal itself. When searching for null values, you must use the `IS` operator. So you need to change your query to include them:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE value !=0
OR value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also replace null for sth else what is not a zero using `isnull` or `coalesce`

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE ISNULL(value,1) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is a "non-value". Some comparing-tools will ignore/skip every `NULL`'s. (`NULL` doesn't exists.)

You have 3 Options:

1) Insert a value `(42)` instead of `NULL`. ex.: Set up a default `ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_mytable_value DEFAULT (42) FOR value`

2) Add `NULL` to your query condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE value != 1 OR value IS NULL
```

3) Compare every `0` as `0` and every `else` as `1` within your WHERE clausel:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE 1 = CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1
```